# how to disable header media in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am facing header media issues. I don't want that header area on my top of the website. I tried CSS code

```
.home #wp-custom-header {
    display: none;"
}
```

but it's not working. please check my site for more details [hindizone.in](https://hindizone.in)

Answer (score 0):

```
#site-header {
    display: none;
}
```

...should work for your site.

Comment: thanx for your time my brother

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better solution to change your theme template file so there is no such div container to be hidden. This can normally be found in **header.php** file of your theme. Delete the div with the class `header-bottom`.

Another way would be using CSS as you already tried. But you do not have an element with id `wp-custom-header` so this code is doing nothing. You can find out the right element to target with using the inspector of your browser.

I did this with your code and therefore found the classes you need to address in your css file.

Add following code to your custom css in the theme editor, or inside style.css of your theme:

```
#site-header.top-header .header-bottom {
    display: none !important;
}
```

With the `!important` statement you make sure, that the display value is not being overwritten somewhere else in your stylesheet.

Comment: thanx its working inspect section love your support thanx man appreciate your support

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer if it solved your issue. Thank you!

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable reply